How to run sendmail as another other user?
I am witnessing behaviour I cannot explain.
If I run sendmail as another user by executing the following commands seperately - that is, typing each command and pressing enter before entering the next:
su - otheruser
cat mailBody.txt | sendmail -t user@domain.com

Then mail is succesfully delivered, and is received as originating from otheruser@mydomain.com.
However, if I try to achieve the above in a single line, the mail continually is seen as being sent from root. I cannot understand why. The methods I have tried to achieve this are:

Running a subshell:
(su - otheruser; testMail.txt | sendmail user@domain.com)


Entering all the commands in a script myScript.sh and running:
./myScript.sh



Both of the above send mail as the user root@localhost.localdomain. Why are the above returning different results to executing the commands separately on the command line ? How could I run sendmail as another user from a single line ?


Why are the above returning different results to executing the commands separately on the command line

Because su doesn't actually switch your shell to a different user – it starts a new shell under the new user, while the original shell is waiting for it to exit.

Normal:
bash [user_one]
 +-- cat testMail.txt [user_one]
 +-- sendmail [user_one]


When su is used as a separate command:
bash [user_one] (waiting for 'su' to exit)
 +-- su [root]      (waiting for 'bash' to exit)
      +-- bash [user_two]   (reading your keyboard input)
           +-- cat testMail.txt [user_two]
           +-- sendmail [user_two]


When su ; cat|sendmail is used:
bash [user_one] (waiting for 'su' to exit)
 +-- su [root]      (waiting for 'bash' to exit)
 |    +-- bash [user_two]   (reading your keyboard input)
 |
 +-- cat testMail.txt [user_one]    \  (will be run
 +-- sendmail [user_one]            /   when 'su' exits)



In interactive mode, this is almost invisible because both shells receive input from the same "stdin". But scripts or ;-separated commands do not emulate keyboard input – they are processed as a separate source.
To make this work, you need to have su specifically run the new shell with the -c option that specifies a command to run (both su and bash take the same -c):
su -c "cat test.txt | sendmail foo@bar" user_two

This causes 'su' to run bash -c "cat test.txt | sendmail foo@bar" instead of an interactive bash; it will interpret only that command and exit. If only 'sendmail' needs to run as a different user, you can also use:
cat test.txt | su -c "sendmail foo@bar" user_two

sudo works the same way, except it skips the shell and directly runs the command, so if you need to run a whole pipeline, then the shell needs to be specified manually:
sudo -u user_two bash -c "cat test.txt | sendmail foo@bar"

cat test.txt | sudo -u user_two sendmail foo@bar


Amazing - thankyou for your input, the above achieves the output I am after. However, I am confused why the commands in your 2 examples have different owners.
When su is used as a separate command: why is cat executed as user1, if it is being run a subshell belonging to user2 ?
When su ; cat|sendmail is used: Why is the final sendmail command executed as user2, if the subshell run as user2 has already exited ? Wouldn't this command now be running in the original shell, as user1 ?
I can see this is the case, but I am not clear on why this is so. Thoughts are greatly appreciated

Sorry, that's a copy-paste error. In both cases the user should have been identical to the parent shell's user.

Excellent - that all makes sense, cheers !
